# calling method from different class raising "Main method not found in class com.company.UniLink" error

Tags: java, main-method

I am working on this console base application.it is basically a university system on which a student can post different kind of posts and people can reply to there posts.

so, i have this startup class

```
public class startup {

    //not keeping all the student

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boolean flag1 = true;
        **UniLink link = new UniLink();**

        while (flag1 == true)
        {
            System.out.println("**** UniLink System ****" + "\n" + "1. Login" + "\n" + "2. Quit");

            Scanner input_level_1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int responce_level_1=input_level_1.nextInt();

            switch (responce_level_1)
            {
                case 1:{
                    System.out.println("Enter Username : ");

                    Scanner input_level_1_1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String response_level_1_1=input_level_1_1.nextLine();
                    **link.menu(response_level_1_1);**
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                default:{
                    System.out.println("Please Try Again");
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I am using a class called Unilink which is doing all the heavy lifting and running the whole program. I did this for better encapluation and cleaner presentation of the code. My menu class allows to perform following tasks.

```
                "1. New Event Post" + "\n" +
                "2. New Sale Post" + "\n" +
                "3. New Job Post" + "\n" +
                "4. Reply to Post" + "\n" +
                "5. Display my Post" + "\n" +
                "6. Display all Post" + "\n" +
                "7. Close Post" + "\n" +
                "8. Delete Post" + "\n" +
                "9. Log Out" + "\n" +
                "Enter Your Choice : ");
```

but i have been getting this error

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.company.UniLink, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

I appericiate any help

Comment: Google the exception message. It takes less time and aggravation

Comment: @efekctive i understand the error and google it, but it says that my unilink class should have a main method but i actually have a main method in startup claas and just calling methods from unilink.

Comment: It seems that you are not passing the full class of startup when typing “java...” at the prompt

Comment: The full class name of startup

Comment: @efekctive I copy pasted everything in a new project and it worked just fine. Don't know that error came up thou. Thanks anyways

Comment: NP. I have found that trying things first myself is better in the long run